# How do I avoid the alternating row color on this HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, asp-classic, rows

I'm using the `<table>` tag to format some text into rows and columns, but I don't want the rows to alternate colors.  For some reason this is happening automatically and I don't know how to turn it off.

Here is my HTML:

```
<table class="homepage" summary "list of dplans">
<div class="options">
    <ul>
        <% @dplans.each do |dplan| %>
        <tr class ='' "list">
            <td class="button"><%='' link_to dplan.name, dplan %></td>
            <td class="button">
                <%='' link_to "edit name", edit_dplan_path(dplan )%>
            </td>
            <td class="button"><%='' link_to "delete", '#'%></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
</table>
```

And here is my css:

```
 td.button {
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: A screenshot would be great. Try `background-color: transparent;` in your `td` selector.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the  tag has any styling by default, so chances are there's some other CSS that's causing this.  The best way to figure this out is to look at a developer tool like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com), which can tell you exactly where that background-color is set.

If you just want to override it, you can try something like:

```
td {
    background:none;
}
```

Comment: @steffi2392 What didn't work?  Inspecting the elements in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you nested a `<div>` tag as a child to a `<table>`. Which is wrong. The only tags permitted for this are `<tr>`,`<th>`,`<tbody>`, etc...

```
 <table class="homepage" summary "List of dplans">
                    <% @dplans.each do |dplan| %>
                     <tr class = "list">
                      <td class="button"><%= link_to dplan.name, dplan %></td>
                      <td class="button"><%= link_to "Edit name", edit_dplan_path(dplan )%></td>
                      <td class="button"><%= link_to "Delete", '#'%></td> 
                     </tr> 
                    <% end %>
</table>
```

See if this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'm bad at formatting - but it didn't make any difference.  Still alternating colors.

Comment: Than Chazbot's comment would be relevant